# Gaussian Elimination Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, gaussian

I m trying to make a parallel program for Gaussian Elimination with Java.

I am making 2 random matrices A and B at the start and i am not using pivoting.

My code when i create the  threads is :

```
  GaussianElimination threads[] = new GaussianElimination[T];
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {


        /**This for statement creates threads that behave like objects
         * With the start() method we execute the run() proccess .And with
         * Join() the main thread wait for all the other threads to finish
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            threads[i] = new GaussianElimination(T, k, i, A, B);

            threads[i].start();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            try {
                threads[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("this should not happen");
            }
        }
    }


    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    float time = (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0f;
    System.out.println("Computation time: " + time);
```

After this the run method is :

```
class GaussianElimination extends Thread {
    private int myid;
    private double[] B;
    private double[][] A;
    int k;
    int threads;


GaussianElimination(int threads, int k, int myid, double[][] A, double[] B) {
    this.A = A;//Matrix A
    this.B = B;//Matrix B
    this.myid = myid;//Id of thread
    this.k = k;//k value from exterior loop
    this.threads = threads; //size of threads
}

/**Method run() where the threads are running .
 *
 * The distribution of the data are in cyclic mode.
 * e.g. For 3 threads the operation of each thread will be distribute like this:
 * thread 1 = 1,4,7,10...
 * thread 2= 2,5,8,11...
 * thread 3 =3,6,9,12...
 */
public void run() {
    int N = B.length;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();//Clock starts
    for (int i = myid + k + 1; i < N; i += threads) {
        double factor = A[i][k] / A[k][k];
        B[i] -= factor * B[k];
        for (int j = k; j < N; j++)
            A[i][j] -= factor * A[k][j];
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float time = (endTime - startTime) ;//clock ends
        System.out.println("Computation time of thread: " + time);
    }
  }
}
```

After that i am doing a back substitution serial and the i print the solution.

So the program is running but it isnt running in parallel.
I have tried to check the time between every thread but it didnt come to a solution.

I couldn't find a lot of examples in java for similar problems so i am asking here.

Is it bad architecture and logic or is any coding errors in my programm?

Also here is the serial code that i used https://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-gaussian-elimination-algorithm/

Thank for your cooperation!

Comment: Java has its own threading model.  I can't imagine that Java will work well with an external threading library like pthreads.

Comment: actually i have only  import java.lang.Thread;

Comment: You say it isn't running in parallel - how do you know this?

Comment: i open task manager and i see the current running processes.